# Change chapter number without header / hide word "chapter"

Tags: microsoft-word

In my document my figures are formatted so they give the chapter number first then the number (e.g. figures in chapter 1 are Figure 1.1, Figure 1.2, etc.). The chapter headings are set with a style that does Chapter #:

I want the leading "chapter" number to change to 6 in my appendices, but I don't want it to be called Chapter 6, because it's not a chapter, it's an appendix. But I want my figures to start with 6. because they are no longer in chapter 5. Without putting in the heading "Chapter 6" then the figures won't update correctly. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does [How to number headings and figures in Appendixes in Microsoft Word | ShaunaKelly.com](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html) answer your question?

Comment: Or [How to insert captions that include chapter numbers, in documents where some Heading styles are not built-in](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/AppendixCaptions.htm)?